# Understanding author's choice for assigning datetime.datetime = self

Tags: python, datetime, self

I am trying to understand the following code, specifically line 5 (the line that is commented out, I commented that out myself).

```
  >>> class PartyTime():
    ...     def __call__(self,*args):
    ...         imp.reload(datetime)
    ...         value = datetime.datetime(*args)
    ...         #datetime.datetime = self 
    ...         return value

    ... etc
    >>> p = PartyTime()
    >>> print p(2013,2,14)
    2013-02-14 00:00:00
```

As you can see, line 5 is commented out `#datetime.datetime = self` yet the function behaves normally. Why did the author include that line? You can see the full article [here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/) (its about half way down). What would the assignment to `self` help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an example of so called "monkey patching". The line commented out makes a change in an imported module, `datetime`.

After `p(2013,2,14)` is executed (if you do not comment out the line), the code

```
datetime.datetime()
```

does not do what it usually does, but executes `__call__` on the `p` instance.

It is generally bad practice, so I would not refer to it as authors choice for writing good software, but just an example. The author himself described it as a silly idea:

> Since everything in Python is essentially names bound to objects, we can do silly (but interesting) stuff like this

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was bad code, just wanted to know what difference it would make.